# Services, OAuth and a mobile app

Tags: services, authentication-authorization

I'm struggling with Drupal, OAuth and a (Cordova) mobile app I'm developing. I've made a custom module and it exposes data to the Services module. What I want to do now is get that data into my mobile app.

I've set up my endpoint, but I need authentication of course.

I've read the tutorials on 3-legged and 2-legged authentication, but from what I've read, I (think I) want the Client-flow. This is the flow where the user enters his/her username and password in the app.

Can anyone get me started on this flow? Is it even possible with Services and OAuth?

Tell me if you need any more info. I'm a developer, but mainly in the .NET space. I've managed with Drupal modules so far, but I find OAuth quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a poorly worded question, so I'm answering the questions you asked, probably not what you really want though..

Both 3-legged and 2 legged work in Services with the OAuth module and the Services_oauth module enabled. I wrote a lengthy article on how to set this up [here](http://www.workhabit.com/blog/using-oauth-drupal-ios-sdk), and documentation [here](https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk/tree/2.x#oauth)

But that doesn't really answer your question in terms of If I can help you get started with your flow. I suggest you ask a new question with the problems you're currently having rather than asking if we can help you get started on a solution we know nothing about.

This may help you understand why this is an extremely tough question to answer. [Asking smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: True, it is a badly worded question (even though I'm no newbie to the SO platform :s ). I should probably just delete it... I'll be sure to check out your blog, thanks.

Comment: Not to worry, just try to be more specific about where you're falling flat and maybe we may be able to help you stand back up!